# Putting 'that' after 'have always been'

Tags: present-perfect

What I've known so far concerning the usage of *past perfect* is that this tense will be used when someone did something and he/she wants to talk about it in the present or the event itself still holds in the present (that'd be my best definition of its usage).

However, there was a sentence from my book that has confused me:

> That argument is out-of-date in a modern technology. Our position
> **has always been** that we should encourage technology.

I feel there's a missing word there i.e.

Our position **has always been** [something] that we should encourage technology.

Why did the writer leave that *something* out if my prediction is correct? Did he/she try to introduce **their position** since **x**?

Comment: In the present tense we could write "our position is that we should encourage technology". What extra word would you insert there?

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm not sure, that's my point of my question. I would put an adjective there and then put *that* bla bla to exlain the detail. Or perhaps verb? However, I'm not sure.

Comment: It's fine. The content clause is complement of "been" in its specifying sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A position is a noun, so after "*Our position has always been...*", we should expect a noun, the same way as if it were the simpler, "Our position is..."

The words, "that we should encourage technology" form a *noun clause*, which means it's a noun.

So your sentence is correct as is, and nothing is missing.